# How to set non utf charset in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, perforce

When I try to connect to my perforce server I get the following error. I have specified utf8 in the P4CHARSET variable in the config what should I set it to get this working?

```
ERROR: Unable to communicate with perforce.  Unicode clients require a unicode enabled server.
For Command: p4 -s client -i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means that your Perforce server is not running in Unicode mode.  You should unset the P4CHARSET variable.

If you just need to store files with non-ASCII content, you can use file type utf16.  If you need Perforce metadata (e.g. user names and labels) to have non-ASCII characters, you need to ask your Perforce admins to switch the server to Unicode mode.

Unicode issues can be a little tricky, so talk to Perforce support if you need detailed help.